# How does the Realm Mobile Platform scale?

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

You could say I am a fan of the Realm Mobile Platform. I'm using it and it seems to be working well.

However I am confused with how to operate it going to production. It seems to be deployed only to one server, and even the professional and enterprise editions are working on my single server.

Assuming Realm have thought of this (as Enterprise edition supports 'enterprise scaling) - how does this work if all clients point to my owned server URL?

Another question is how to monitor the load on that server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Professional Edition and the Enterprise Edition emit `statsd` compatible metrics which allow you to track the usage and load on each node in a Realm Object Server cluster. These metrics are also used internally inside the cluster in order to display statistics about the health of the cluster.

We are obviously still adding metrics as we understand more about our customer's use-cases, and fine-tuning the ones that we have.

With regards to the way the clustering works, we are currently implementing this according to an iterative process, where we add more and more features, and more and more resilience to the system with every passing day.

Basically, we have a logical load balancer process, which receives the incoming client connections, and then dispatches that to a node inside the cluster. This logical load balancer can be HA'd and LB'd itself as well, just like you would any regular WS connection handler. Handling many connections these days is easy. It's handling the quadratic merge algorithms that is expensive on the Realm Object Server, which is why the clustering is required for deployments at scale.

Comment: Still open: Since the development, professional and enterprise are deployed on the same single server (for example, Digital Ocean) only by a different key. I understand all users being directed to that specific server (IP), how would that ever scale?

Comment: Single IP isn't really limiting. You can use DNS round-robin load balancing, VRRP to share an IP across hosts, use a physical (or virtual, with HA) load balancer, etc.

Comment: Is that being done by the RMP for me automatically just by installing the pro/enterprise editions?

Comment: We try to make things as easy as possible, but if you have specific infrastructure needs, you'll need to get some infrastructure ;). VRRP, for example, is a specific protocol. ROS is just a high-level daemon, it can't do low level things like manage the system's IP address.